# As a support, should I ever leave the AD carry?

Tags: league-of-legends

As a support, should I ever leave the AD carry?

I find that I stay bot for a long time, warding, and getting to at least gp10. 
Then when I get boots I look for a few things:

- where wards need to be placed globally
- Look to see if a champion on my team is dominating

If I have a champ on my team dominating and outpacing the AD carry for whatever reason, I will start supporting them.

Is this reasonable? Or should I always be supporting the AD carry or at least trying to support the AD carry?

Comment: Stay with the AD carry, unless you are playing a champion that can pull of a gank on mid, or possibly even counter jungle a little

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Early game, you'll probably follow only your carry. You may leave him in some circumstances:

- Warding river / red / blue to keep track of junglers (prevents ganks and allow counter jungle)
- One of the enemy botlane switch to another lane, you MUST follow and let your carry take care of the lane (if he can't 1v1, he's a bad carry). Some times though, it may be more effective to stay here to deny farms and let your carry fill/create a gap. But be sure other lanes are doing fine and won't be impeded by one or more champion in the lane (bot + jungler)

Do not leave him if a champion is dominating at this moment. Keep an eye on when the enemy begins to team up. Before that point, your carry may be able to invert the steam and come back in the game. But he won't do it alone.

In mid game, you have to support the "real" carry of the game. Don't waste your energy on a bot AD carry that is 0/8/2 when you have a 10/2/22 top. He is the one who must stay alive (worth much gold, high damage burst, high disruptive power allowing team to score, ...). If the intended carry (a.k.a. bot champion) did not get enough farm/kills, forget about him. He must try to fill in the gap as he can, with farms on incoming creeps or so.

In late game, you have to be were there is a team. You won't be efficient if you're going duo with an AD carry (unless maybe if he's hard fed). Your auras should benefit the maximum of champions.

Comment: Great answer, just want to add on that if you're not pushed back and the enemy support is a traditional support (sona, soraka, taric) it's ok to leave to get wards if you're out. It's better to have your AD miss out on 20 seconds of farm then to give enemy team two kills and a free dragon.

Answer (score 1):

Early to Mid game you should always be along with the AD carry, warding the lane, and out-zoning the enemy lane.

Once bottom tower is taken down, and where more team fights occur, you should always be looking after your AD carry as 1st priority, however you should use all effort available in saving any teammate in trouble i.e the 2nd most important the AP carry.

For obvious reasons if your AD carry is farming a lane, and the rest of your team is about to face a team fight you should go straight ahead into supporting them.

A dominating champ out-pacing the AD carry not necessarily needs you as bodyguard, the role of the AD carry is unique, nevertheless another teammate is having better kda or cs.

Comment: Extending your first line: an AD carry left to solo bot lane could be put under pressure: killed, zoned out and/or tower lost.